# Aligning text symmetrically

Tags: html, css

I have a 3 column website, the left column is for displaying fixtures. My problem is my text is not aligning the way I want it to as you can see in the image below:

[image]

I would like the text to align directly under each other in a symmetrical way, if that makes sense?

The CSS I am using is as follows:

```
   //this is for the left box
    #leftbox{
    float:left;
    width:300px;
    height:1000px;
    border-right: 1px dotted #f00;
    border-bottom:none
}

//this is for the fixtures
#fixtures{
    position:relative;
    top: -20px;
}

//this is for the image R in fixtures
#fiximg{
    position:relative;
    top: 5px;
}
```

Im using a PHP include file called fixtures, so I dont have too change fixtures manually on each page.

```
<?PHP

echo '<center>';
  echo'<h3>Super Rugby Fixtures & Predictions</h3>';


  //DATE1 COMES HERE           
   echo'<u>Friday 21 February</u>';


    //FIXTURE1 COMES HERE   
echo'<p id="fixtures"><strong>Crusaders vs Chiefs</strong><a href="super_rugby_preview.php"><IMG id="fiximg" src="images/fixtures/preview.png"  /></a> 06:35am(SA Time)<BR />';

     //Fixture 2
echo'<p id="fixtures"><strong>Cheetahs vs Bulls</strong><a href="super_rugby_preview.php"><IMG id="fiximg" src="images/fixtures/preview.png"  /></a>19:05 (SA Time)';
echo'<br>';    
          //DATE2 COMES HERE           
  echo'<u>Saturday 22 February</u>';
echo'<br>';  


      //FIXTURE COMES HERE   
echo'<p id="fixtures"><strong>Highlanders vs Blues</strong><a href="super_rugby_preview.php"><IMG id="fiximg" src="images/fixtures/preview.png"  /></a> 08:35am(SA Time)<BR />'; 

    //FIXTURE2
echo'<p id="fixtures"><strong>Brumbies vs Reds</strong><a href="super_rugby_preview.php"><IMG id="fiximg" src="images/fixtures/preview.png"  /></a> 10:45(SA Time)<BR />'; 

      //fixture3
echo'<p id="fixtures"><strong>Sharks vs Hurricanes</strong><a href="super_rugby_preview.php"><IMG id="fiximg" src="images/fixtures/preview.png"  /></a> 17:05(SA Time)<BR />'; 

    //fixture4
echo'<p id="fixtures"><strong>Lions vs Stormers</strong><a href="super_rugby_preview.php"><IMG id="fiximg" src="images/fixtures/preview.png"  /></a> 19:05(SA Time)<BR />';  

       //DATE4 COMES HERE
  echo'<u>Sunday 23 February</u>';  

       //fixture
       echo'<p id="fixtures"><strong>Waratahs vs Force</strong><a href="super_rugby_preview.php"><IMG id="fiximg" src="images/fixtures/preview.png"  /></a> 19:05(SA Time)<BR />';    


echo'</center>';

        ?>
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @witherwind Ill attach it now

Comment: Maybe a fiddle, so that your question won't be too long to read. :)

Comment: Can you describe in more detail how you *want* it to be aligned?

Comment: @witherwind I just attached it

Comment: Why don't you put it in a table?

Comment: @colllin I would like all the R images to be aligned directly under each other

Comment: Then a table should do it.

Comment: @winterwind thats actuallya good idea

Comment: And maybe you can put the texts in an array and loop them using foreach(). That should simplify your code.

Comment: Don't `echo` too much. In PHP, you can just do: `<?php /*php code here*/ ?> <!-- HTML code here --> <?php /*php code again*/ ?>` so for yours you don't even need `<?php ?>`, just code in HTML.

Comment: If you want to avoid a table, another option is to specify a width on the team names container.  You will probably need to ditch the `<center>` for a normal `<div>`, and add `#fixtures strong { text-align:right; width:200px; overflow:hidden; text-overflow:ellipsis; display:inline-block; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like doing these projects just to learn a bit more about HTML/CSS.

This [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/timspqr/p6T7G/) just uses divs (although tables would be OK because it truly is tabular data) in a variety of "holders" that allows you to easily add more lines. Given your PHP requirements, it would also be just as easy to add `<?php echo $mydate ?>`. There are hundreds of ways to do it, this is just one.

CSS

```
.holderdiv {
  width: 70%;
}
.datediv {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
.gamebox {
  float:left;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.leftdiv {
  float: left;
  width: 43%;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: 20px;
  border: 0px solid black;
}
.rightdiv {
  float: left;
  width: 43%;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 20px;
}
.logodiv {
    float: left;
    width: 5%;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    background-color: #cccccc;
    border-radius: 5px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you didn't attach any HTML, this is what I came up with from the CSS:

*HTML:*

```
<div id ="leftbox">movie 1</div> <div id="fiximg">R</div> <div id="fixtures">don't bring kids</div>
<br>
<div id ="leftbox">movie 19</div> <div id="fiximg">R</div> <div id="fixtures">terrifying</div>
```

*CSS:*

```
#leftbox{
    float:left;
    display:inline-block;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    border-right: 1px dotted #f00;
    border-bottom:none
}

#fixtures{
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
    height:100px;
    width: 100px; /*just for consistency*/
}

#fiximg{
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
    height:100px;
    width:20px; padding-left: 5px;
    border-right: 1px dotted #f00;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/t82u2/

Key is `display:inline-block;`.

If you need any help you can contact me.